# how can i make a function see a variable outside it

Tags: php

How can I place a variable inside a function when it is run in order to preg_match the right information.  Here is my existing code:

```
$username = "test";
function is_txt($file) {
return preg_match('/backup-[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+_[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}_'.$username.'.tar.gz/', $file) > 0;
}
```

What I am attempting to do is pull the $username variable from outside the function and allow it to be seen within it so I can pull the right matches in my while loop.  While the previous comes back blank, if i do the following it works:

```
$username = "test";
function is_txt($file) {
$username = "test";
return preg_match('/backup-[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+_[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}_'.$username.'.tar.gz/', $file) > 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import the var with `global`:

```
function is_txt($file) {
    global $username;
    return preg_match('/backup-[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+_[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]  {2}_'.$username.'.tar.gz/', $file) > 0;
}
```

But passing the value in as a parameter as explained by Jonah is a better solution in most cases.

Answer (score 2):

Modify the function to take the `$username` variable as a parameter:

```
function is_txt($file, $u) {
return preg_match('/backup-[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+_[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}_'.$u.'.tar.gz/', $file) > 0;
}
```

Then call it like:

```
$username = "test";
is_txt($file, $username);
```

Alternatively, you can use the `global` keyword to make the variable visible from the function. This is sometimes useful, but shouldn't be used all over the place. See the [variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) manual entry for more info.